# How can i get back dodge maximized windows function for Launcher in 13.10?

Tags: unity, launcher

I still can't understand why the developers completely removed the function to let the Launcher dodge only maximized windows but is there a way to get this function back by tweaking dconf or so?
this question is explicit to 13.10 where none of the patches or hacks work!

Comment: If I understood correctly, [here is what you are looking for.](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/how-to-get-unity-launcher-window-dodge.html)

Comment: Any further updates to this question will be found on the duplicate question now in your question.  Thanks.

Comment: no, that doesn't work in 13.10! But it is exactly what i'm looking for and what was a functionality in older Ubuntu versions!

Comment: We do not want a question "for each version of Ubuntu" but a question "for any version of Ubuntu". BTW, have you tried this one? http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/how-to-get-unity-launcher-window-dodge.html